# Problem with Chat client program

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server chat and client chat programs running on localhost. When I try to connect to the server my client program freezes on next line `in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());` 
here is a piece of code where I try to connect to the server

```
            Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
            try {
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                Message m = new Message(null, nick, Message.Type.REGISTER);
                out.writeObject(m);
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                socket.close();
                throw ex;
            }
```

Message class implements  Serializable interface, so it can be serialized over the network. And here is a piece of code where server hadle client request

```
try {
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream()));
            Message m = (Message) in.readObject();
            switch (m.getMessageType()) {
                case REGISTER:
                    registerUser(m);
                    break;
                case CHATMESSAGE:
                    sendMessageToAll(m);
                    break;
                case UNREGISTER:
                    unregisterUser(m);
                    break;
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Chatserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Chatserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

methods registerUser, unregisterUser, sendMessageToAll simply call next method

```
private void sendMessage(Message m, Socket s) throws IOException {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()));
        out.writeObject(m);
        out.flush();
       // out.close();
    }
```

Where is a mistake?

Comment: what is `client` in the sample above?

Comment: it is the socket of specified client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem might be the same as the one described [here.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/232944/threads/java/Socket-getInputStream-block)

Answer (score 0):

Just faced this problem .. So giving the answer in this thread itself :

ObjectOutputStream writes a stream header when we create it  (new ObjectOutputStream(out))

Similarly , ObjectInputStream , when we create it  (new ObjectInputStream(in)) , tries to read the same header from the corresponding ObjectOutputStream at the server side

Here , in client ,

```
in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

the ObjectInputStream created blocks when trying to read the stream header , which will not come since there is no corresponding ObjectOutputStream at server which will write the header to the client .

The problem is not just this . If the ObjectOutputStream creation at one side aligns with some  other reads at the client side which is supposed to read something of our choice , it may read the stream header instead of the actual value and end up in an incorrect value .

Solution :
The ObjectOutputStream and the ObjectInputStream created at the client and server sides must align with each other .